# fusion table: link two location with line

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

Right now each row of my data contains two locations i.e. source and destination. Can I show some kind of link eg. a line between these locations within Maps in Fusion Table. I guess I might have to learn KML for that and will have to modify my data. Is their any other way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create a  result like this "on the fly", you must modify your data, e.g. by adding a new column based on source and destination.

The KML-syntax would be like this:

```
<LineString>
<coordinates> [source.lng],[source.lat] [destination.lng],[destination.lat]</coordinates>
</LineString>
```

Example for a line from New York to Chicago:

```
<LineString>
<coordinates> -74.0059731,40.7143528 -87.6297981,41.8781136</coordinates>
</LineString>
```

Note: when you define coordinates in KML the order is `longitude,latitude` , it's different from the Maps-APIs.

Comment: adding extra column should be easy using Google refine :). Lets see if this works. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly this seems to draw a straight line in terms of the 2d map, rather than a straight line on the surface of the earth which would appear curved on the 2d map. I tried setting the altitudeMode to "clampToGround" but no joy so far